# compare substring sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello Stackoverflow team,

Im tring to compare col1, if substring('col1', 4,2) is alphanumeric then cat_type = substring('col1', 4,2) else NULL.
Hope that is clear.

My code is below who can help me, please.

```
(case when col1 like '%Datum%' then 'Date' 
      when col1 like '%Datumin%' then 'Date' 
      else ''
      end) as T1, 
        if isnumeric((substring (col1, 4, 2))) 
        then cat_type = substring (col1, 4, 2) as cat_type
``
```

Comment: Assuming col1 is the column name, remove the quotation marks. 'col1' is treated as a string literal. And get rid of the(x)

Comment: Thank you @JonathanWillcock i have edited the origina post

Comment: Your sample data does not look correct.  The third argument to `substr()` is a length and none of your examples are 9 characters.  Plus, for the last one, the characters starting at 4 are all "alphanumeric".

Comment: You originally tagged Postgresql and now changed to Mysql. In your question you say: "if substring('col1', 4,2) is **alphanumeric**..." and in your code you use `if isnumeric()`. Also there is no isnumeric() function in mysql. Your question is still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the question you *asked*:

```
(case when substring('col1', 4, 5) ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'
      then substring('col1', 4, 5)
 end) as cat_type
```

This returns the results you specify based on the data:

```
(case when substring('col1', 4, 2) ~ '^[0-9]+$'
      then substring('col1', 4, 2)
 end) as cat_type
```

Comment: thank you very much its very useful @Gordon Linoff I realised in my data i have white spaces in the beggining that can affects the results. I mean the 5th position after the first written letter.

Comment: do you see what i mean ? hope that im clear. and thank you again. :)